# Google Maps - get address of the current map position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building a website that uses Google Maps. There is a div conatinint the map that can be moved about with the pointer.

I need to get the nearest street address of the currently centred view in the map. How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [gmap geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), you can find the json array of coordinate by directly pass it to url, for example

[location: lat:40.714224, lng:-73.961452](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false&key=)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not quite what I need. The map will be integrated in a page, and I need to dynamically display the street address of the map centre, whereby the map could be moved around. So the url needs to stay unchanged, but the address should be fetched depending on the map view.

Comment: As I understand, you want to retrive the address of the map's center, right? So it could be done by googlemap reverse geocoding, see

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?hl=en

If you want to dynamically retrieve the address, you can set the drag listener to your map, get the center latlng, and apply the reverse geocoding to get the address.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Map's GeoCoding:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```